# javascript mouse events

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

Is there a way in javascript to make it so that an "onclick" works for all members of a particular class? So if I have objects A and B that are both of type X, clicking on either of them will call the same function? But that function should only work on whichever of A or B was called, not both at the same time.

Because basically what I'm trying to do is when I click on either A or B they move to a different location, but I want this to be able to work for any arbitrary number of n elements in the same class

Comment: Not a clear question. post some codes

Comment: If you accept an answer using jquery, please specify your question to that extend: Change title and tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/2BRS9/

Add the same class for all those html elements . You can get the element from which the event was fi

If the classname is "myclass"

```
  $(".myclass").live({
      click: function(e){
      // You can get id by many ways, some shown here :
      id= this.id;
      console.log(id);
      id = $(this).attr("id");
      console.log(id);
      id = e.target.id;  
      console.log(id);

   }
```

});​

Comment: As JQuery is not mentioned in the question, this should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type="button" class="abc" value="A" />
   <input type="button" class="abc" value="B" />
   <input type="button" class="abc" value="C" />
   <input type="button" class="abc" value="D" />


 $(".abc").click(function() {
  alert("any of the above is clicked");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.classname_of_member').bind('click',function(){
//your code here
});
```

Comment: Do I need to put any html tags around this?

Comment: No,just write the code inside the function.it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can make use of "this" keyword.

for e.g

```
<input type="button" class="abc" value="A" />
<input type="button" class="abc" value="B" />
<input type="button" class="abc" value="C" />
<input type="button" class="abc" value="D" />


$(".abc").click(function() {
 $(this).hide(); // for hiding the only the clicked element.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written some simple code to handle mouse operations including click, double click, right click and drag and drop.
[www.derbyshiresoftware.co.uk/how-to-handle-mouse-operations/][1]